# How to get list of user accounts and access through root in Ubuntu terminal?

Tags: users, root, permissions

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 and there are 5 users for the machine.
I have the root password and I want to see the list of users and access the account through root in terminal.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 5):

`sudo -i` will turn you into root and looking in `/home/` is usually a good indication on who the system's *real* users are but you can do this account-wise by searching for users with uids over 1000 with:

```
awk -F: '$3 >= 1000 && $1 != "nobody" {print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

If you want *all* the system users, look in `/etc/passwd`.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the usernames of the Users by using the following command

```
awk -F":" '{ print "Linux_name: " $1 "\t\tFull_Name: " $5 }' /etc/passwd
```

If you want more details just modify the script to your needs.All the equired information are found in /etc/passwd.