Ubuntu 24.04 tty login incorrect
I am facing the tty login loop where I am not able to get out of, guess why I don't remember the username.
It asks for login then password.
My password is correct but username is not correct after trying a bunch of them which it would have been but no luck.
I am not able to access the grub either as Ubuntu is single boot and the boot screen goes off quickly, I tried with ESC but at times it gives me a blink of something and then just disappears into the tty login.
Is this still a solve-able issue or should I look for complete factory reset of my laptop if possible or just a bit new one .

Try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/640334/how-can-i-find-my-ubuntus-username

This question is similar to: How can I find my ubuntu's username?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
